# reference request: existence of a complete model of a G-variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Sumihiro has a result in this paper: http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.kjm/1250523277, to the effect that a variety $X$ with an action by a linear algebra group has a complete model (as a $G$-variety).
Besides this paper, could I find a reference to the result, and its proof elsewhere?

Thanks!

Elliot

Comment: What do you mean by model? If you want just a variety which is birationally equivalent to $X$ and complete, then it is rather standard fact: by definition there is an affine open subset, embed it in projective space and take the closure. Notice, there is no compatibility with group action. Do you require some conditions?

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your reply. I mean a model, as a $G$-variety. What that means is this: $X$ is a $G$-variety, and a complete model of $X$ will be a complete variety $X'$ such that $X'$ is complete AND $X'$ is a $G$-variety, and finally that it is equivariantly birational to $X$. Note that there is apriori no $G$-action on the projective closure in what you are saying.

Comment: I can prove it in affine case. If you want, I can write it (but probably you know it better than me). But I do not see how one can reduce non affine case to affine case ($G$ invariant affine open set do not have to exist).